# How to make entire window aero glass in Java?

Tags: java, aero, aero-glass

I am trying to program a small application but I would like the entire window to be glass with buttons and labels on top of it. Is it possible to do this within Java?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming Java SWT and friends do not have built-in support for Windows Aero technology, you're going to have to call a native API via JNI. The native API you'll need to call is

```
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(int windowHandle, MARGINS margins);
```

This native API is found in the DWMAPI.dll native library in Windows Vista and Windows 7, and is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512(VS.85).aspx).

There's lot of documentation on the web about how to call this function. For example, here's an article on [doing this in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/AeroGlassForms.aspx). That should get you started.

Comment: It should be noted that SWT has some internal APIs for calling DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea. That might be a starting point for figuring this out.

Answer (score 4):

Of course this feature is highly platform-dependent (Windows, in this case) so JNI is needed.

Let's assume you have already checked that glass windows are enabled. The steps are:

1. ensure that the window is layered;
2. extend the glass frame into the client area;
3. choose a color that identifies transparent areas;
4. set that color as window background.

Steps 1-3 are written in C. Let `HWND hwnd` a handle to the window you want to glassify and let `COLORREF color` a color (the more unusual, the best):

```
// 1.
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
// 2.
MARGINS margins = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);
// 3.
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, color, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Step 4 is simple Java, something like

```
window.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
```

where `color` is the Java version of the color chosen before.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm. I think that all Java GUI must be displayed, directly or indirectly, in a `Window`, and that's a heavyweight component. Not sure if you can make it transparent/translucent.

Try building a JFrame and setting its background color to `new Color(255, 255, 255, 20)` or so, where 20 is the alpha. That should either make it mostly transparent - or it won't work.